# Getting a Component that is not a child to receive props from another Component

Tags: reactjs

My Components -

ProfileHeader 

--Notifications


Post

--Comments

--LikePost

I would like Notifications Component, which is in ProfileHeader Component, to receive props when a user comments on a post or likes a post. I would like the Notifications Component to receive props so that it can update and re-render the new notification. Example of what I would like to be able to do below:

```
handleLikeCount(){
    let count = this.state.likeCount;

    let dummyData = {
        username: 'hatface',
        userid: '0201',
        date_posted: '(data)',
        display_picture: '(image)'
    }

    if(this.state.liked){
        this.setState({
            likeCount: count - 1,
            liked: false
        }, () => {
            <Notifications notificationFrom={dummyUser} />
        }); 
    }
    else{
        ....
    }


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

- define a component that will be the parent of both ProfileHeader and of Post. The posts will be in this new component's state. This new component will pass callbacks to its children components. These callbacks will be called by the children components when they want to change posts.
- use redux, define global state that will be accessible from multiple components

Comment: Thank you! Will try these options out